# How could a git tag trigger a build plan in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

When a tag pushed to a git repo hosted by Phabricator, I want to use herald to trigger a build plan.

But I find that I can't do this, because the type of commit hook (tag/branch) in herald rule can't trigger a build plan.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[The Phabricator docs](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hooks/) say:

> if Herald isn't powerful enough to enforce everything you want to
> check, you can install additional custom hooks. These work mostly like
> normal hooks, but with a few differences.

> **Git** Put hooks in `hooks/pre-receive-phabricator.d/`.

There's no mention of `post-receive` so I don't know if you can just use a standard `post-receive` script or copy.

Git post-receive scripts will be called on any new refs, including tags. There's [an example in the git repository](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email) that sends emails for new commits and tags and could be repurposed to trigger a remote build via `curl`. Unsure if or how this can be hooked into Harbormaster.